# How do I exclude matched values from a particular $_GET variable in an apache rewrite rule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to omit certain values for the $_GET variable of "?main_page=" within an apache rewrite rule. For example:

I have some URLs I want to rewrite, such as:

```
http://example.com/index.php?main_page=faq
http://example.com/index.php?main_page=login
http://example.com/index.php?main_page=contact_us
```

to become:

```
http://example.com/faq
http://example.com/login
http://example.com/contact_us
```

I was able to achieve this with:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} main_page=(.*)
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1? [R=302,L]
```

However, I would also like to omit certain values of "?main_page=" from the rewriting rule, such as:

```
http://example.com/index.php?main_page=index    
http://example.com/index.php?main_page=page&id=2
http://example.com/index.php?main_page=advanced_search&search_in_description=1&keyword=cialis&inc_subcat=0
http://example.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1&products_id=27
```

So I tried something like:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} main_page=(?!product_info)(?!page)(?!index)(?!advanced_search)
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1? [R=302,L]
```

but no luck. I'm not great at regx rewrites.  I'm hopeful it's a small error I'm making. Could anyone please offer some help? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To negate multiple key values, you can use :

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} main_page=((?!index|product_info|page|foo|bar).*)
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! And I learned something new today ;)